# Enemy rendering

Tags: java, rendering

I'm creating "tile game"[image]

The question I would like to ask is: let's say that my map is gonna be 5000*5000 tiles and as you can see I already got some enemies there (two red piles-slimes :D) the problem is that I would like to have cca one enemy per 500 tiles so 5000*5000/500 which results in about 50000enemies which is impossible to render at once so I've got rectangle object which holds the actual screen that player can see and if the hitbox of the "slime" intersects the rectangle then Im rendering it, but the problem is that I still have to loop through each of those slimes to see whether their hitbox isnt in the screen rectangle after the player moved, is there anyone who ever had similar problem ? If so could you tell me your solution ?

Comment: You probably need to organize your elements in larger chunks. Don't consider all slimes all the time, but understand which one are close to the visible area, and which are further away.

Comment: Interesting issue. I haven't ever had to tackle this problem, but my initial thought coincides with that of other posters: limit your area of concern to what is closest to the visible zone. Additionally, you could likely calculate intersections in parallel, since whether one Slime's zone intersects is largely independent of whether or not another one intersects. (E.g., if you implement the stream api, you could use `stream().parallel().filter(Code or method that results in True if enemy does intersect and False otherwise)`.) This would likely improve processing speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the problem is that I still have to loop through each of those
>   slimes to see whether their hitbox isnt in the screen rectangle after
>   the player moved,

Looping through **some** slimes when the player moves is normal or rather acceptable but looping through **all** slimes is not.
You should probably maintain a structure where you know for each tiles area the enemies that are present on.
  A tiles area should gather a certain number of tiles but beware you should find/adjust its size to make it not too small (you lose interest of that as you have to inspect many of them) and not too big either (you will loop on many enemies that may be too far).

The overall idea is so checking the enemy presence only for tiles area close form the player.   A structure such as `Map<TilesZone, List<Enemy>>` may make sense or maybe `TreeMap<TilesZone, List<Enemy>>` to benefit from `NavigableMap` interface that could be helpful in your use case.